# running wscat or websocat from CRON - no output

Tags: cron

I'm trying to get some data from a network device via a web socket.  On the command line, the command works fine.  But when executing from cron the only thing that happens is the output file is created with 0 bytes in it.  I've tried with/without the `SHELL` variable.
How do I capture/redirect the output of the command?

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/1 *  *   *   *     /usr/bin/wscat -c ws://therm9.local/ws -w 1 >/dev/shm/outsideTelem 2>&1
# or
*/1 *  *   *   *     websocat -U --one-message ws://therm9.local/ws >/dev/shm/outsideTelem
```

file:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 pi     pi           0 Aug  7 12:40 outsideTelem
```

syslog:

```
Aug  7 12:45:01 raspberrypi CRON[21791]: (pi) CMD (/usr/bin/wscat -c ws://therm9.local/ws -w 1 > /dev/shm/outsideTelem 2>&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash as the shell, it looks like the output redirect is slightly different.

`&>` vs `>`

So the below started putting messages into the file `/dev/shm/outsideTelem`:

`websocat -U --one-message ws://therm9.local/ws &>/dev/shm/outsideTelem`